# Unity: How to represent grid map data in ECS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to work with Unity's pure ECS approach to make a basic nxn grid of tiles.

Before using ECS I would just use a 2d array `Tiles[,] grid` where I can simply index (x,y) to find the tile I want.

Now moving into ECS, I want to create an entity for each tile using an IComponentData struct like so:

```
public struct Tile : IComponentData
{
    public int xIndex;
    public int yIndex;

    public int isValid;
}
```

Somewhere during the start of my game I create the tile entities

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tilesInMap; i++)
    {
        Entity tileEntity = entityManager.CreateEntity(tileArchetype);

        int xIndex = i % terrainSize;
        int yIndex = i / terrainSize;

        entityManager.SetComponentData(tileEntity, new Position { Value = new float3(xIndex , 0, yIndex) });

        Tile newTile;
        newTile.xIndex = xIndex;
        newTIle.yIndex = yIndex;
        newTile.isValid = 1;

        entityManager.SetComponentData(tileEntity, newTile);
    }
```

Now somewhere else in my code I have a `ComponentSystem` that pulls in the tiles using a group struct

```
public struct TileGroup
{
    public readonly int Length;
    public EntityArray entity;
    public ComponentDataArray<Tile> tile;
}

[Inject] TileGroup m_tileGroup;
```

As far as I'm aware, as long as I don't change the archetype of any of those entities in the TileGroup (for instance by calling `AddComponent` or `RemoveComponent`), the ordering of that injected array will be preserved (I'm not even sure of that!)

So say in my `OnUpdate` method I want to "get the tile at grid coordinate (23, 43)". I can calculate this (assuming a 1d array of tiles with the order preserved) by

```
int arrayIndex = yIndex * tilesPerMapWidth + xIndex;
```

But this only works as long as the injected array order of tiles is preserved which I doubt it will be eventually.

So a few questions:
1. Should I ever rely on the order of an injected array for behaviour logic?
2. Are there any better methods in achieving what I want using ECS?

Comment: I don't know how Unity ECS works, but relying on assumptions (like the ordeR) is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the Unity forums, "[Order of Entities](https://forum.unity.com/threads/order-of-entities.524241/#post-3443977)":

> - ComponentDataArray<> / ComponentGroup makes zero gurantees on the actual ordering of your entities except for that its deterministic. But generally the indices are not stable. (E.g. Adding a component to an entity, will change the index in ComponentDataArray of that entity and likely of another one) The only stable id is the "Entity" ID.

To answer your questions:

> So a few questions: 1. Should I ever rely on the order of an injected array for behaviour logic?

Based on "...makes zero guarantees on the actual ordering of your entities..." I would say no.

> 2. Are there any better methods in achieving what I want using ECS?

You don't need *arrayIndex* to access entities in your tile group. You can iterate through the entities and access x and y for each to perform the required behavior. Depending on your actual functionality you may want to use the job system as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_tileGroup.Length; i++) {
    int x = m_tileGroup.tile[i].xIndex;
    int y = m_tileGroup.tile[i].yIndex;
    // do something with x and y
}
```